# Replacing a lot of absolute links at once

Tags: javascript, html, css, wordpress, web

I started on a project where we want to go from a Wordpress site we currently have to a non-cms based site for specific reasons. I downloaded a plugin for the site which converted all my pages and such to HTML but now I have a bunch of pages with absolute links to certain wordpress folders that will not be there anymore.

I would like to (for the time) convert all links that use absolute paths to relative paths as I have changed the file structure of the website. I currently use Sublime 3 and Phpstorm, but if those tools can't help me I can absolutely get another one to help me with this task.

Thanks!

Comment: Text editor, find and replace?

Comment: Sublime Text absolutely lets you do this. Besides find/replace you can also select multipl places on a page by highlighting a piece of text and hitting Ctrl - D. See "Quick Add Next" https://www.sublimetext.com/docs/2/multiple_selection_with_the_keyboard.html

Comment: This is however the wrong site for this question. It should be on http://superuser.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Notepad++ is powerful for this. Use Find and replace in all files from a selected directory.
If you are on linux, use grep.